# How I can get rpi3 jessie image system source code？

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi3, debian-jessie

Not the Raspberry Pi 3 kernel source code, but the whole Jessie system source code. How can I get that and build it? Is there a tutorials? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The source code of Jessie consists of many parts:

- The Linux kernel : http://www.github.com/raspberrypi/linux
- Most Packages : please refer to `apt-get source` command
- Some modified packages : please refer to https://github.com/raspberrypi?tab=repositories
- The source codes of some **closed-source software** are unavailable (e.g., Oracles JVM)

For further imformation, you may refer to [this link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/48223/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-of-raspbian-jessie/48230#48230).

Comment: what I want is to generate my own system image file，so can down my image to another hardware or share to other guys. but use "dd" command it will backup the whole file which is too large.  so I cannot do this ?

Comment: I have not found a whole image source code that exactly you want from the raspberry pi image [mirror site](http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/). I mean that the official source code of the **whole** Jessie is unavailable. You may raise an issue on GitHub or try to compile Rpi Kernel first, here is a [brief guide](http://elinux.org/Raspberry_Pi_Kernel_Compilation).